# read a file line by line into structure

Tags: c

code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
   FILE *fp;
   const char s[3] = "  "; /* trying to make 2 spaces as delimiter */
   char *token;
   char line[256];

   fp = fopen ("input.txt","r");
   fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);

   token = strtok(line, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL )
   {
      printf( " %s\n", token );

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
return 0;
}
```

input.txt is like below :

```
01  Sun Oct 25 16:03:04 2015  john  nice meeting you!
02  Sun Oct 26 12:05:00 2015  sam  how are you?
03  Sun Oct 26 11:08:04 2015  pam  where are you ?
04  Sun Oct 27 13:03:04 2015  mike  good morning.
05  Sun Oct 29 15:03:07 2015  harry  come here.
```

i want to read this file line by line and store it in variables like

```
int no = 01
char message_date[40] = Sun Oct 27 13:03:04 2015
char friend[20] = mike
char message[120] = good morning.
```

how to achieve this ?
is it possible to store the file line by line into a structure like

```
struct {
int no.;
char date[40];
char frined[20];
char message[120];
};
```

with above code i am getting following output:-
(currently i am reading only one line for simplicity)

```
 01
 Sun
 Oct
 25
 16:03:04
 2015
 john
 nice
 meeting
```

you!

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried? This is certainly possible, and showing that you've made some attempt with help people answer your question based on your current approach.

Comment: Of course it's possible!  Read the data into a buffer, parse it to find the token boundaries, and store the appropriate items.  If you want to copy the data, then do so.  If not, write null values into the buffer at the end of each entry and store the pointers to the start of each in your struct.

Comment: I strongly suggest you start reading a book on C. The problem is that simple that apparently you don't know C. Start learning & coding!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no coding or effort is provided.

Comment: Is it possible? yes. How to achieve? hundreds of ways, I'd probably use `fgets()`, `strncpy()` and `atoi()`. Nothing to be seen here, ask a question when you actually run into problems :)

Comment: @WilliamPursell with spaces as delimiter i am not able get it as i want.

Comment: _trying to make 2 spaces as delimiter_  `strtok` doesn't work such as. use `strstr` instead of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `fgets()` to read each line of the file and `sscanf()` to parse each line. The scanset `%24[^\n]` will read up to 24 characters stopping on a newline. The date format has 24 characters so this reads the date. The scanset `%119[^\n]` reads up to 119 character to prevent writing too many characters into `message` and stops on newline. `sscanf()` returns the number of fields successfully scanned so 4 indicates the line scanned successfully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Text {
    int no;
    char date[40];
    char name[20];
    char message[120];
};

int main( )
{
    char line[200];
    struct Text text = {0,"","",""};

    FILE *pf = NULL;

    if ( ( pf = fopen ( "input.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ( "could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ( ( fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), pf))) {
        if ( ( sscanf ( line, "%d %24[^\n] %19s %119[^\n]"
        , &text.no, text.date, text.name, text.message)) == 4) {
            printf ( "%d\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", text.no, text.date, text.name, text.message);

        }
    }
    fclose ( pf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strstr` instead of `strtok` like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void){
    FILE *fp;
    const char s[3] = "  "; /* trying to make 2 spaces as delimiter */
    char *token, *end;
    char line[256];

    fp = fopen ("input.txt","r");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    if(end = strchr(line, '\n'))
        *end = '\0';//remove newline
    fclose(fp);

    token = line;
    while(token != NULL){
        if(end = strstr(token, s))
            *end = '\0';
        printf("'%s'\n", token);
        if(end != NULL)
            token = end + 2;//two space length shift
        else
            token = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```